# Django: How to perform User validation in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using custom users and I would like to perform validation on user creation directly in models.

The reason I don't want to do this validation in forms only is because User objects can be created from somewhere else (e.g. API, Django shell, etc.)

**The problem**: currently, validation is correctly performed on email (note that I removed username field).
But how am I supposed to do to validation on password? Currently, an empty password works, so I guess there is no validation at all. I'd like to use my `REGEX_PASSWORD = r'[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,}'` to perform pwd validation.

Here are my UserManager class and User class:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        ''' Creates and saves a User with the given email and password '''

        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)

        user.full_clean()

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # Ce champ définit le username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Aucun autre champ requis à part email et pwd
```

Comment: just override the method `set_password` and do what you need to do over there (+ then call its parent)

Comment: Thanks! I detailled your answer to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the yedpodtrzitko idea, here what I did:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    if not re.match(REGEX_PASSWORD, raw_password):
        raise ValidationError(ERR_BAD_PWD_FORMAT)
    super(User, self).set_password(raw_password)
```

It works, thanks for this.

The only thing I'm not very comfortable with is that when I use a signup Form to create my user, it performs a double-validation on the data (first time with the form validators, second time with the model itself). It's not very DRY...

I let the answer unaccepted in case there is better.